# URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

I tried upgrading my cakephp version from 1.3 to 2.5 but encountered an url rewriting problem. Another cakephp app runs on the same version so I'm sure the mod_rewrite works.

Although when I go to example.com/pages/home I get following error:

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.    1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

When I go to my normal home page and I want to click on a home link I get following url :

http://example.com/app/webroot/index.php/

And it is the same for other urls.

http://example.com/antwerp becomes http://example.com/app/webroot/index.php/antwerp

When I go to http://example.com/antwerp the site works as it should...

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: sounds like you haven't updated your `index.php` file or your `Config/core.php` file to match the version of cake you're using. Btw CakePHP 2.5 doesn't exist.

Comment: I should have written 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest accessing your account and re-uploading your .htaccess files from and to the following locations respectivelly.

```
/app
    .htaccess
    /webroot
        .htaccess
.htaccess
```

Some FTPs do not upload those files automatically until you force it to.

If that does not work, check if you have your `php.ini` file in your public_html folder of this application.

Comment: I've copied the code from each file individually and also uploaded the ftp files individually with no success :(

Comment: I added a line about the `php.ini` file on the bottom of my Answer